# 401 Unauthorized from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I am using this cmd on windows to upload my package in testpypi `twine upload -r testpypi dist/*` but it's showing this error. so how to upload in testpypi and pypi when 2FA is enable ?

```
Uploading mypackage-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8.5/8.5 kB • 00:00 • ?
WARNING  Error during upload. Retry with the --verbose option for more details.
ERROR    HTTPError: 401 Unauthorized from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
         User has two factor auth enabled, an API Token or Trusted Publisher must be used to upload in place of password.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create API token from your pypi account then give `username =__token__` and `password=APIToken`after cmd `twine upload -r testpypi dist/*`

or
if you are using Twine to upload your projects to PyPI, set up your $HOME/.pypirc file like this:

```
[testpypi]
  username = __token__
  password = API Token
```

Comment: you may need to change [testpypi] to [pypi]

Comment: but that forces me to create a token with all project scope for a first push right ?