# How to uplaod on pypi.test with 2fa?

Tags: pypi, google-2fa

I try to update my package and test it on pypi.test. But now it is required to set up a 2 factor authentication method (2fa). I set it up, but still can not upload. Why ?

Here is what I tried :

```
(main) ostocker@ospc2:~/travaux/OSToolBox$ python -m twine upload --repository-url 
https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/* 
Uploading distributions to https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
Enter your username: nanblanc
Enter your password: 
Uploading OSToolBox-1.5-py3-none-any.whl
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14.8/14.8 kB • 00:00 • 137.4 MB/s
WARNING  Error during upload. Retry with the --verbose option for more details.                     
ERROR    HTTPError: 401 Unauthorized from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/                             
         User NanBlanc has two factor auth enabled, an API Token or Trusted Publisher must be used  
         to upload in place of password.
```

This means I need to use the code generated by google authenticator:

```
(main) ostocker@ospc2:~/travaux/OSToolBox$ python -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/* 
Uploading distributions to https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
Enter your username: nanblanc
Enter your password: 
Uploading OSToolBox-1.5-py3-none-any.whl
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14.8/14.8 kB • 00:00 • 123.2 MB/s
WARNING  Error during upload. Retry with the --verbose option for more details.                     
ERROR    HTTPError: 403 Forbidden from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/                                
         Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See                                    
         https://test.pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information.
```

I can not understand this error. If it isn't the 2fa code that I should use, what do I need to use then? (I tried password with and without the space: "XXXXXX" or "XXX XXX", doesn't change a thing)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57508957/7976758 2FA only affects **logging in via a web browser**, and not (yet) package uploads. For uploading you need an API token. See https://pypi.org/help/#apitoken , https://stackoverflow.com/a/76888958/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpypi%5D+2fa

Comment: yes indeed it anwered my questions, thanks. I needed to genereate an API-token But i didn't knew what it was before reading your links. You can post your comment as en answer, i will accept it :)

Comment: No need to have the second answer. :-)